# Can I set the predicted values of a neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

My question is more theoretical than practical but I can show some code as well. I have network that is mapping from random values in a domain uvw, to a xyz domain. I want a certain values of the uvw to go to other certain values in the xyz that I already know, since that is the idea of the function that I want to obtain and I want the network to over-fit.

My question is divided into two questions:

1. Can I set the predicted values I want into the network so it doesn't have to calculate those predicted values?
2. Does this is going to affect prediction of the other values?

This is my code, I want to show it so we have some notation that we can talk about.

```py
 # The model is a simple fully connected network mapping a 3D parameter point to 3D
    phi = common.MLP(in_dim=3, out_dim=3).to(args.device)

    # Eps is 1/lambda and max_iters is the maximum number of Sinkhorn iterations to do
    emd_loss_fun = SinkhornLoss(eps=args.sinkhorn_eps, max_iters=args.max_sinkhorn_iters,
                                stop_thresh=1e-3, return_transport_matrix=True) # TODO add r-1 function to the weights  

    mse_loss_fun = torch.nn.MSELoss() 


    # Adam optimizer at first
    optimizer = torch.optim.Rprop(phi.parameters(), lr=args.learning_rate)

    fit_start_time = time.time()

    for epoch in range(args.num_epochs):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Do the forward pass of the neural net, evaluating the function at the parametric points
        y = phi(t)

        # Compute the Sinkhorn divergence between the reconstruction*(using the francis library) and the target
        # NOTE: The Sinkhorn function expects a batch of b point sets (i.e. tensors of shape [b, n, 3])
        # since we only have 1, we unsqueeze so x and y have dimension [1, n, 3]
        with torch.no_grad():
            _, M = emd_loss_fun(phi(t[num:]).unsqueeze(0), x[num:].unsqueeze(0))
            _, Q = emd_loss_fun(phi(t[0:num]).unsqueeze(0), x[0:num].unsqueeze(0)) 
            P[0,num:,num:] = M[0]
            P[0,0:num,0:num] = Q[0]
            #print(y[Q.squeeze().max(0)[1], :])





        # Project the transport matrix onto the space of permutation matrices and compute the L-2 loss
        # between the permuted points
        loss =  mse_loss_fun(y[P.squeeze().max(0)[1], :], x)
        # loss = mse_loss_fun(P.squeeze() @ y,  x)  # Use the transport matrix directly

        # Take an optimizer step
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        print("Epoch %d, loss = %f" % (epoch, loss.item()))
```